# WPF - How to set my image source bind to another text

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, binding

Here is my code:

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="120">
<Image Name="First_Image" Source="{'Tag of Second_Image'}" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="80" Height="80" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="10"/>
<Image Name="Second_Image" Uid="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="80" Height="20" Canvas.Bottom="20" Canvas.Left="10"  
MouseLeftButtonDown="TTX" Tag="/Images/Image.png" Style="{StaticResource Function}"/>
</Canvas>
```

I'm trying to set my first image source equal to Tag of Second_Image. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ElementName Binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Second_Image}" .../>
<Image x:Name="Second_Image" Tag="/Images/Image.png" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks a million. You saved my ass.